# View grouped records in a date or time sequence. Possibly a log table grouped by level

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Say you had a table in your SQL Server (EDIT: prensently SQL Server 2008) database that look like this:

```
Date                    Id State
=================================
2013-09-12 15:02:41,844 1 OK
2013-09-12 15:02:41,844 2 OK
2013-09-12 15:02:41,844 3 ERROR
2013-09-12 15:02:41,844 4 ERROR
2013-09-12 15:02:41,844 5 ERROR
2013-09-13 15:02:41,844 1 ERROR
2013-09-14 15:02:41,844 1 OK
2013-09-15 15:02:41,844 1 ERROR
2013-09-15 15:02:41,844 2 ERROR
```

The purpouse of the table is to save records state. I wrote this table but now i cannot figure out how to query it for an overview of the different states during a time sequence.

The result i am looking for is this:

```
2013-09-12 16:00:00 OK 2
2013-09-12 16:00:00 ERROR 3
2013-09-13 16:00:00 OK 1
2013-09-13 16:00:00 ERROR 4
2013-09-14 16:00:00 OK 2
2013-09-14 16:00:00 ERROR 3
2013-09-15 16:00:00 OK 0
2013-09-15 16:00:00 ERROR 5
```

**EDIT**: What i am trying to achieve is a day-by-day view of the state of my objects. which objects has an error and which ones are ok.  Maybe a garage would be a better example, but i will stick to this.

- On the 12th 3 objects had ERROR and 2 where OK.
- On the 13th one object went from OK to Error. I now have 4 objects in a ERROR state   and one that is OK.
- On the 14th my object with id 1 is fixed and i am now back to two objects that are OK >and three that has an ERROR state

I have figured out (found) how to generate a sequence of dates (without using variable declarations) like this:

```
;WITH dates
AS (
    SELECT CAST('2013-12-17 16:00:00' AS DATETIME) 'date'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, t.DATE)
    FROM dates t
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, t.DATE) <= GETDATE()
    )
SELECT dates.DATE   
FROM dates
```

And i have a query that does the relevant grouping (i think) that delivers a desired output (and point):

```
Date State Count(state)
=======================    
2013-09-12 16:00:00 OK 2
        2013-09-12 16:00:00 ERROR 3
        2013-09-13 16:00:00 ERROR 1
        2013-09-14 16:00:00 OK 1
        2013-09-15 16:00:00 ERROR 1
```

So the question is, how do you marry the sequence of dates to my grouping result  to achieve the desired result.

Comment: I like the cte. Problem is, it only returns as many dates (+/- 1) as you have levels of recursion enabled...

Comment: I don't quite understand your requirements. What are you trying to count? My first guess was "count of each state value for the 24hr period prior to the reporting datetime." But I can't figure out how you will get Count=4 for "Error" and "2013-09-13".

Comment: what are the columns in your output? for example i really don't see where `2013-09-13 16:00:00 OK 1` comes from

Comment: I made two edits that hopefully clearifies your questions.

Answer (score 1):

With SQL Server 2012 providing window functions you can use the following query:

```
SELECT date,
       sum(ok_mod) over (order by date) as ok
FROM (
  SELECT date,
         sum(case when state = 'OK' then 1
                  when state = 'ERROR' and prev_state is not null then -1
                  else 0
             end) as ok_mod
  FROM (
    SELECT date, id, state,
           lag(state) over (partition by id order by date) prev_state
    FROM data
  ) AS data
  GROUP BY date
) AS data
ORDER BY date;
```

This gives you only OK part, but you can easily union corresponding query for ERROR part also. SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4bdfe/15).

With 2008 version imho you won't make it without a procedure or really complex query.

Comment: THank you for your help. Too bad i am currently stuck on a 2008 environment. My Bad. I will test this as soon as we move to 2012 wich will be any other week now.