# Get history of record states sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Say I had a Bus Garage application that contained a datatable that represented wether buses where either in the garage, out of the garage or in the shop for maintenance. It looks like this:

```
+-----------------------+-----+-----+
|Date                   |BusId|State|
+-----------------------+-----+-----+
|2013-09-12 15:02:41,844|1    |IN   |
+-----------------------+-----+-----+
|2013-09-12 15:02:41,844|2    |IN   |
+-----------------------+-----+-----+
|2013-09-12 15:02:41,844|3    |OUT  |
+-----------------------+-----+-----+
|2013-09-12 15:02:41,844|4    |OUT  |
+-----------------------+-----+-----+
|2013-09-12 15:02:41,844|5    |OUT  |
+-----------------------+-----+-----+
|2013-09-13 15:02:41,844|1    |OUT  |
+-----------------------+-----+-----+
|2013-09-14 15:02:41,844|1    |IN   |
+-----------------------+-----+-----+
|2013-09-15 15:02:41,844|1    |OUT  |
+-----------------------+-----+-----+
|2013-09-15 15:02:41,844|2    |OUT  |
+-----------------------+-----+-----+
```

Now i want to make a nice day-by-day (or hour by hour etc) dataset giving me an overview of how many buses where in the garage an how many that where out of it.

```
+-------------------+-----+------------+
|Date               |State|Count(buses)|
+-------------------+-----+------------+
|2013-09-12 16:00:00|IN   |2           |
+-------------------+-----+------------+
|2013-09-12 16:00:00|OUT  |3           |
+-------------------+-----+------------+ 
|2013-09-13 16:00:00|IN   |1           |
+-------------------+-----+------------+
|2013-09-13 16:00:00|OUT  |4           |
+-------------------+-----+------------+
|2013-09-14 16:00:00|IN   |2           |
+-------------------+-----+------------+
|2013-09-14 16:00:00|OUT  |3           |
+-------------------+-----+------------+
|2013-09-15 16:00:00|IN   |0           |
+-------------------+-----+------------+
|2013-09-15 16:00:00|OUT  |5           |
+-------------------+-----+------------+
```

How (not necessary explained in code) would i go about to do this just using TSQL?
I have one reqirement, and that is that i can not use variable declarations in my statement since i will have this as a View.

I asked a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047157/view-grouped-records-in-a-date-or-time-sequence-possibly-a-log-table-grouped-by/21052321), but i felt that that one got too verbouse and not as general as this one.

Comment: somethin like: `select Date,State,Count(*) from table group by day(date),state`

Comment: That query misses two things: It would not give me the dates when no buses where changing state and it does not take into account the buses that did not change state on a particlular day. Look at the desired resultset again.

Comment: it was just a hint. (that wy its here and not in Answer)

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want multiple records per day/hour just to display the different states? I would make them columns. You can use a CTE and the `OVER` clause to count per day/hour group:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT [Date] = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, [Date]),0), 
           [BusId], [State],
           [IN]  = SUM(CASE WHEN State='IN'  THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, [Date]),0)),
           [Out] = SUM(CASE WHEN State='Out' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, [Date]),0)),
           [DayNum] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, [Date]),0)
                                         ORDER BY [Date], [BusID], [State])
    FROM dbo.Garage g    
)
SELECT [Date], [BusId], [State], [IN], [OUT]
FROM CTE 
WHERE [DayNum] = 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/66c6e/6/0)</kbd>

Result:

```
DATE                               BUSID   STATE   IN   OUT
September, 12 2013 00:00:00+0000    1       IN     2    3
September, 13 2013 00:00:00+0000    1       OUT  (null) 1
September, 14 2013 00:00:00+0000    1       IN     1    (null)
September, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000    1       OUT  (null) 2
```

This works even in SQL-Server 2005. If you want to group by hour instead of day you have to change `DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, [Date]),0)` to `DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, [Date]),0)` everywhere.

Comment: The end result i want is a table like that, but i tried to simplify the question to the core problem (in my opinoin)

However your answer misses one thing: I would like to have the counts to summarize the state of all buses belonging to the garage. So the counts on september would be 4,1 not null, 1

Comment: @Fontanka16: it's not clear why 4,1. But you can also use `[Total] = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, [Date]),0))` to get the count of all in-outs per day. Or change the logic accordingly. You can even partition by multiple columns if you want to include the `BusId`.

Comment: 4,1 because in the state table 1 bus changed state that day. The result is that 4 buses are out and 1 is in the garage

Comment: Just to be clear: I do not want the query to reflect the state changes  per date, i want the query to reflect on the state for all of the buses on that date.

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
DECLARE @businfo AS TABLE([date] datetime,busid int,[state] varchar(5))

INSERT INTO @businfo VALUES('2013-09-12 15:02:41',1,'IN')
INSERT INTO @businfo VALUES('2013-09-12 15:02:41',2,'IN')
INSERT INTO @businfo VALUES('2013-09-12 15:02:41',3,'OUT')
INSERT INTO @businfo VALUES('2013-09-12 15:02:41',4,'OUT')
INSERT INTO @businfo VALUES('2013-09-12 15:02:41',5,'OUT')
INSERT INTO @businfo VALUES('2013-09-13 15:02:41',1,'OUT')
INSERT INTO @businfo VALUES('2013-09-14 15:02:41',1,'IN')
INSERT INTO @businfo VALUES('2013-09-15 15:02:41',1,'OUT')
INSERT INTO @businfo VALUES('2013-09-15 15:02:41',2,'OUT')


select [date],[state],COUNT(busid) as [count(buses)] from @businfo
group by [date],[state]
order by [date]
```